# storing a GPG key in AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, gnupg, amazon-kms

I have a series of files in AWS S3, encrypted with a GPG public key. I want to store the private key in AWS KMS, so I can programmatically decrypt them.

I have followed AWS docs for BYOK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys.html) but cannot encrypt my private key with the AWS wrapping key as it's "unable to load private key" when I follow step 2 of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys-encrypt-key-material.html.